# How to enable disabled inputs when multiple option is selected using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-select

I ran into a problem. How can I enable disabled inputs if I have selected multiple items in select tag and disable it again when I removed the selection?

```
<div class="form-group mb-3">
  <select class="selectpicker show-tick decore" name="state" id="state" multiple>
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">
      <i class="fas fa-child"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="first" id="first" class="form-control" placeholder="first" aria-label="first" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" disabled />
</div>
<input type="text" name="second" id="second" class="form-control" placeholder="second" aria-label="second" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" disabled />
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OrbQxm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `change` event handler for `select` tag and in function, check if length of `selected` option is less than `2` remove `disabled` attribute and if is great than `2` add it to element.

```
document.getElementById("state").onchange = function(){  
  var length = this.querySelectorAll("option:checked").length;
  document.querySelectorAll("#first, #second").forEach(function(ele){
    ele.disabled = length < 2;
  })
}
```

```js
document.getElementById("state").onchange = function(){  
  var length = this.querySelectorAll("option:checked").length;
  document.querySelectorAll("#first, #second").forEach(function(ele){
    ele.disabled = length < 2;
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group mb-3">
  <select class="selectpicker show-tick decore" name="state" id="state" multiple>
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">
      <i class="fas fa-child"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="first" id="first" class="form-control" placeholder="first" aria-label="first" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" disabled />
  <input type="text" name="second" id="second" class="form-control" placeholder="second" aria-label="second" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" disabled />
</div>
```

Also you can do this work using **jQuery** with less code

```
$("#state").change(function(){  
  $("#first, #second").prop("disabled", $(":selected",this).length < 2);
});
```

```js
$("#state").change(function(){  
  $("#first, #second").prop("disabled", $(":selected",this).length < 2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group mb-3">
  <select class="selectpicker show-tick decore" name="state" id="state" multiple>
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">
      <i class="fas fa-child"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="first" id="first" class="form-control" placeholder="first" aria-label="first" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" disabled />
  <input type="text" name="second" id="second" class="form-control" placeholder="second" aria-label="second" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" disabled />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm using JQuery solution. Work like a charm. But can you modify your code a bit? I also need to enable input when only one item is selected. And make 'em required when they active

Comment: I need a solution when only one input becomes active, when I select only one element from the list, and if all elements are selected, then both inputs become active, and are also disabled if the selections from the items have been removed. Hope you understand what I mean. phew.